# How to convert BootStrap dropdown on hover into Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert my BootStrap dropdown on hover menu into wordpress. I am using Underscores as a base theme and I am stuck the HTML menu is as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown navbar-header pull-right">
    <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx btn-default navbar-btn dropbtn">
                            <span>toggle menu</span>
                        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have done the following the header.php file:

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array (

    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
    'container'         => 'nav',
    'container-class'   => 'dropdown navbar-header pull-right',
    'menu-class'        => 'dropdown-content'));
?>
```

Can someone please help me? I am inexperienced in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would place that code in the `.dropdown-cotext` div keeping everything else the same

```
<div class="dropdown-content"> 
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array (
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'items_wrap'        => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'));
    ?>
</div> `
```

You would then have to register the menu in your functions file, I would place it in the setup function:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => esc_html__( 'Header Menu', 'theme_name' ),
) );
```

Note I identified the menu by the location

Comment: what happens if I identify it with the Primary Menu, would it still work?

Comment: Im assuming you mean the menu name ive set as "Header Menu" ? In that case no, as that is the name displayed to the user as they are editing the site (In the customiser of the site). The theme_location is only used to ID the menus, you would set the actual menu displayed in wp-admin panels (in the customiser).
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/

Comment: Yes that is informative. I will stick to Header Menu as you stated.